# Finding mixed degree polynomials in Scikit learn support vector regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, svm, non-linear-regression

as I understand, support vector regression in Scikit learn takes an integer for the degree. However, it seems to me as if lower degree polynomials are not considered.

Running the following example:

```
import numpy
from sklearn.svm import SVR
X = np.sort(5 * np.random.rand(40, 1), axis=0)
Y=(2*X-.75*X**2).ravel()
Y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - np.random.rand(8))
svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=2)
y_poly = svr_poly.fit(X, Y).predict(X)
```

(as copied and slightly modified from here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html)

Plotting the data gives a rather poor fit (even when skipping line 5 where a random error is given to the Y-values).

It seems like lower order terms are not considered. I tried to pass a list `[1, 2]` for the `degree` parameter but then I got an error for the `predict` command. Is there any way to include them? Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: You set the penalty C to 1000, it basically penalizes any effective parameters. Try setting it to 1 or less

Comment: It helps, but it does not solve my general question to what extent lower order terms are considered.

Comment: This comment https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152610/extremly-poor-polynomial-fitting-with-svr-in-sklearn is very useful, however I cannot infere from it if lower order terms are included or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the lower order polynomial terms are included in the fitted model but are not visible in the plot since the `C` and `epsilon` parameters are not well suited for the data. One can usually obtain a better fit by fine-tuning the parameters with `GridSearchCV`. Since in this case the data is not centered the `coef0` parameter also has a significant effect.

The following parameters should give a better fit for the data:

```
svr_poly = SVR(kernel='poly', degree=2, C=100, epsilon=0.0001, coef0=5)
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought for a "simple" model, the hyperparameters would not be that important. I will accept the answere as it lead me to an example which shows more clearly that they are included. I will provide it as an answere, too.

Answer (score 1):

`scikit-learn.SVR` runs lower order polynomial. A modification of the original example shows this clearly.

```
X = np.sort(2*np.random.rand(40,1)-1,axis=0)
Y = np.sin(6*X).ravel()
svr_poly1 = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree=3)
y_poly1 = svr_poly1.fit(X, Y).predict(X)
svr_poly2 = SVR(kernel='poly', C=100, epsilon=0.0001, coef0=5, degree=3)
y_poly2 = svr_poly2.fit(X, Y).predict(X)
svr_poly3 = SVR(kernel='poly', C=100, epsilon=0.0001, coef0=5, degree=5)
y_poly3 = svr_poly3.fit(X, Y).predict(X)
```

Plotting this gives

[Result of the different SVR algorithms with two models using order 3 but different hyperparameters and one model using order 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jLFE.png)